# Cómo saber si una imagen ya está en la base de datos (Android / Java)

Tags: java, android, sql

Estoy escribiendo una galería de imágenes para Android conectado a un WebService. El caso es que no sé qué hacer para saber si una imagen en el teléfono móvil ya está en el Servidor.

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
select * from imagenes where id = md5(nueva_imagen);
```

Generaría un md5 para cada imagen y este md5 sería la clave primaria en la base de datos.

La cuestión es que jamás he hecho nada igual y no sé si esta esta una buena aproximación o hay alguna forma mejor de hacerlo.

Si fuera adecuado, ¿cómo se puede generar un md5 de un Bitmap en Android/Java?

Gracias.

Comment: Un bitmap es un archivo.. todos son archivos.. y por lo tanto son datos y se puede obtener un hash o un md5 de ellos. abrelo como un archivo y tendras todos los bytes en hexa que quieras para calcular el codigo que quieras. Dicho esto, la pregunta es muy amplia.

Answer (score 1):

## Opinión acerca del método

Debes tener en cuenta que cualquier algoritmo hash puede ser colisionado en una probabilidad de 1 / (tamaño hash). En el caso del hash MD5 se ha demostrado que la probabilidad de colisión puede ser inferior y, por lo tanto, ya no se aconseja su uso.

## Mejora propuesta

Te recomendaría usar SHA y, además, incorporar más datos de la imagen además de su hash como su tamaño en bytes (usa [File.length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) para ello). Eso reducirá enormemente la probabilidad de colisión.

## Implementación hash MD5 en Android

Para calcular el hash MD5 de un archivo puedes usar la siguiente clase desarrollada por el equipo de [CyanogenMod (este es el código de la versión 14.1)](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_CMUpdater/blob/cm-14.1/src/com/cyanogenmod/updater/utils/MD5.java):

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 The CyanogenMod Project
 *
 * * Licensed under the GNU GPLv2 license
 *
 * The text of the license can be found in the LICENSE file
 * or at https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
 */

package com.cyanogenmod.updater.utils;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class MD5 {
    private static final String TAG = "MD5";

    public static boolean checkMD5(String md5, File updateFile) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(md5) || updateFile == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MD5 string empty or updateFile null");
            return false;
        }

        String calculatedDigest = calculateMD5(updateFile);
        if (calculatedDigest == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "calculatedDigest null");
            return false;
        }

        Log.v(TAG, "Calculated digest: " + calculatedDigest);
        Log.v(TAG, "Provided digest: " + md5);

        return calculatedDigest.equalsIgnoreCase(md5);
    }

    public static String calculateMD5(File updateFile) {
        MessageDigest digest;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while getting digest", e);
            return null;
        }

        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(updateFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while getting FileInputStream", e);
            return null;
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int read;
        try {
            while ((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            byte[] md5sum = digest.digest();
            BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5sum);
            String output = bigInt.toString(16);
            // Fill to 32 chars
            output = String.format("%32s", output).replace(' ', '0');
            return output;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process file for MD5", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception on closing MD5 input stream", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Teniendo en cuenta que las imágenes en el dispositivo son archivos, podrías usar la clase de la siguiente manera:

```
File imagen = new File('ruta_al_archivo');
String md5 = MD5.calculateMD5(imagen);
/* En imagen.length() tenemos el tamaño del archivo (leer propuesta) */
```

Si tienes cargado el archivo en memoria (poco recomendado por el uso ineficiente de la memoria si la imagen es muy grande) podrías usar la siguiente función [obtenida de esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4846511/1343773):

```
public static final String md5(final String s) {
    final String MD5 = "MD5";
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                .getInstance(MD5);
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte aMessageDigest : messageDigest) {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & aMessageDigest);
            while (h.length() < 2)
                h = "0" + h;
            hexString.append(h);
        }
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

## Adaptando el código a otros algoritmos hash

Se puede cambiar el TAG de [`MessageDigest.getInstance()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29) a otros algoritmos de hash. Para obtener el listado disponible puedes hacer uso de [`Security.getProviders()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Security.html#getProviders%28%29).

De la [documentación de Oracle de `MessageDigest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest) puedes obtener un listado inicial con:

- MD2
- MD5
- SHA-1
- SHA-224
- SHA-256
- SHA-384
- SHA-512

Answer (score 0):

Intenta que al momento de subir la imagen al servidor, retornar un identificador unico que el servidor el asigno a la imagen. Entonces en tu dispositivo haces creas una tabla de equivalencia donde tendras el nombre original de la imagen y su respectivo identificador en el servidor. Por ejemplo:

```
nombre_archivo     identificador_server
PHOTO_3SDFEF.png   58512
```

Entonces si el usuario selecciona esa imagen, primero buscas en la tabla si existe en la tabla, es porque fue enviado, de lo contrario no.

Ahora bien esto tiene como falla que si el usuario renombrar el archivo en el dispositivo, ya no podrás saber si fue enviado.

Comment: Si borra la app del telefono tambien.. Si borra los datos de la app tambien... No es una respuesta mala.. pero es muy vulnerable.